# cloud function callable [indirect call] test.wrapped(function) vs [direct call] function.run()

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

What is the difference between **test.wrapped(function)** and **function.run()**? Both seems to be running fine under a test runner locally. I used mocha, but I think it will run in same manner under jest as well.

**What is the difference between below two approaches?**

**1. direct call:**

```
.....
.....
.....
funcName.run({foo:"bar"}, { auth: { uid: "ABC" } });
.....
.....
.....
```

**2. [indirect call] using wrap:**

```
.....
.....
.....
const projectConfig = {
  projectId: 'my-project',
  databaseURL: 'https://my-project.firebaseio.com'
};
const test = require('firebase-functions-test')(projectConfig, './service-account-key.json');
wrapped = test.wrap(funcName);
expect(
        wrapped(
            { foo: "bar" },
            { auth: { uid: "ABC" } }
        )
).to.contain('foobar');
.....
.....
.....
```

Is it like we need to use test.wrap() it in order to utilize the additional fuctionallity from test runner? This can be achieved via async await as well but the mentioned one would be convenient to use. For ex. `eventually` from **[chai-as-promised](https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-as-promised)** for promises?

Comment: Hi @Mehul Pamale, if you think my answer helped you, please consider accepting it by clicking the checkmark on the left side under the vote arrows and upvoting it. I'd really appreciate it, Thank you!

Comment: Done! Thank you for your answer. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between the direct & indirect (using wrap) call is that the later approach of using wrapped function utilizes the capabilities from Firebase Test SDK for Cloud Functions - "firebase-functions-test".  Some of those capabilities are -

1. Offers methods for constructing custom data or example data within data parameters.
2. Generation of default eventContextOptions (2nd) parameter to wrapped function in case this parameter is not passed in explicitly.

You may read more around this topic on Cloud Functions public docs for [unit testing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing#test-background) & [corresponding API reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/test/test) for Firebase Test SDK.